# Is "adapt to society" natural English?

Tags: word-request, collocations

I learned that "*go into society*" is not natural because we are born into society; we should say "go into the real world".

How about "*adapt to society*"?

If this is not idiomatic, are there better alternatives? My first thought is "*adapt to the real world*".

Comment: More context would make this a better question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you "learned" that the phrase "*go into society*" is not natural. as [this google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+into+society%2Cadapt+to+society&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows, The phrase "*go into society*"  is in fact used with some frequency. It seems to have been more common in the late nineteenth and early 20th centuries than it has been more recently, although the chart does show an upturn in recent years. As Always With Google Ngrams, one must note the limitations. It reports only examples in published works in the google corpus.

Google books finds the phrase in such works as:

- *Going Into Society* By Charles Dickens ("* "Toby, my ambition is, to go into Society.*")
- *Manners and Tone of Society or Solecisms to be Avoided* (first published in 1897) ("Widowers would wear mourning for the same period, but would go into society at a much earlier date,'''") ISBN 9781473343153,
- *Heroines of French Society in the Court, the Revolution, the Empire and the Restoration* ("...M. de Beaune that, seeing this, she left off talking about it, and he, hoping she was becoming more resigned to the loss, proposed that she should begin again to go into society")
- *Women in European Culture and Society: A Sourcebook* by Deborah Simonton (Page 181: " I was much out of health after my [first] husband's death, and chiefly occupied with my children, especially with the one I was nursing; but as I did not go into society" (ISBN:  9780415684385)
- *Aristocratic Women and Political Society in Victorian Britain by K. D. Reynolds (ISBN: 9780198207276, 1988) (Page 23: "Other royal females , particularly the princess of Wales and Princess Mary of Cambridge , were more inclined to go into Society than the queen , but distance was always maintained.")
- *Balcony Stories* by Grace E. King · (ISBN:  9780808404385; 2014) ("What should girls go into society for otherwise but to meet their brun or their blond? Do you think it is amusing, to economize and economize, and sew and sew, just to go to a party to dance?")
- *Little Dorrit* by Charles Dickens ("If you wish to know the complaint I make against you, it is, in so many plain words, that you really ought not to go into Society, unless you can accommodate yourself to Society.")
- *Complete Works of William Dean Howells* (“He might go into society and get rid of them that way,” Mrs. Denton suggested, with an obliquity which he was too simply masculine to perceive. “I suppose you go into society a good deal, Mr. Ray?”)
- *My Fair Temptress* by Christina Dodd (ISBN:  9780060561123) (Page 33: "IfI say you shall go into society, then into society you shall go. Let anyone who disagrees carry their complaints to the duke of Nevett.")
- *Sons of Fortune* by Malcolm Macdonald (ISBN:  9780394418148) (Page 175: "I think you should do as Stevenson suggests. Go into Society. Especially now you're a baroness.")

One should note that most of these examples are either reprints of older works, dating from the 19th century, or historical novels set more or less in that period.

Anyway, although every person is in some sense a member of society (aside from hermits and people abandoned on otherwise uninhabited islands) the phrase "*go into society*" can mean leaving one's household to mix with a wider population (as almost everyone must do for the first time as some period of life, early or late) or, more often, to mean entering in to a group with a recognized high social status. Such a group is sometimes known simply as "Society" or with a qualifying adjective, such as "Manhattan Society" or "Hollywood Society". In any case this phrase is used quite often enough that I find it quite natural, even something of a cliche.

The phrase "*adapt to society*" is less well known, and Google reports a lower frequency of use. But I see nothing wrong or unnatural about it.  How appropriat it is, and what alt native phrase might be better would depend on the detailed context in which one wanted to use the phrase.